# Error con maven-surefire-plugin al ejecutar tarea Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

He usado spring boot generando maven project con java y spring boot 2.0.3

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test
>   (default-test) on project

¿Alguien conoce este error? Mi pom.xml es este:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.udemy</groupId>
<artifactId>backendninja</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>backendninja</name>
<description>proyecto curso spring udemy</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.6</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Sin más detalles creo que significa que Maven ha intentado, tras compilar todo, a ejecutar los test unitarios y alguno ha fallado

Comment: Lo que dice @Pablo Lozano, usa esta flag en tu maven para evitarlos "-DskipTests"

Comment: ok gracias a los dos

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar de version de Java a la 1.8 como minimo por la version de spring boot que estas usando ademas de quitar `<maven-jar-plugin.version>2.6</maven-jar-plugin.version>` y tambien hacer un mvn clean o borrar la carpeta target dentro de tu proyecto a veces eso pasa